# ResultSet is null while the connection is active and the database works properly

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I try to get certain data from the database using the following code:

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "username", "pwd");
System.out.println("Successfully set!");
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ABSTR_CARS");
ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
```

The ResultSet (`rs` valuable) is always null after execution of this code. Usage of `rs.next()` command leads to `NullPointerException`. I know that the database contains the data I need and that the connection is set (`execute()` method returns true and I double-checked connection using my IDE facilities).
The driver I installed in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.23</version>
</dependency>
```

What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: You need to execute the prepared statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to execute the statement:

```java
statement.execute();
```

after preparing the statement and before retrieving the result set.

You can execute and fetch the result set in one go with a call to [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()).

```java
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's absolutely right.